# Confusion with entities and aggregate roots for patients, dentists, treatments and medical history

Tags: domain-driven-design, aggregateroot, clean-architecture, value-objects

I am new to DDD and decided to practice it with a dental clinic system I'm developing, but I'm struggling with modeling the domain so an extra pair of eyes will be greatly appreciated.
For this dentistry system, the domain expert told me that a patient holds only one medical history. The medical history must have a Record Number which is unique on the system. The medical history holds dental treatments the patient could have (like planned treatments) as well as treatments that the patient already had. Every treatment has a price, and so the medical history contains a Total price on it (based on planned/applied treatments). Whenever a patient gets a treatment done, he/she will have to pay with at least 50% of that treatment price, meaning he/she will eventually pay the rest of it on future appointments (if no treatment plan exists, he/she will have to pay for the 100% of the price). Finally, this dentistry clinic gives the option to patients to pay on different currencies, because sometimes a patient that comes for the day has only Euros, but then he decides he wants a plan and for future appointments will pay on Pounds.

Based on all this, and my beginner knowledge of DDD, my first thinking is that I have these entities:

- Patient
- Treatment
- Dentist

I will have several value objects, but the most important ones might be:

- Money (for prices and currency)
- Signature (for applied treatments)
- Tooth or Teeth (used on Treatment entity)

And I can only find one aggregate which is Medical history since it puts together patient info, as well as treatments (planned and applied). But this will mean that whenever I update a Medical History, I will have to update patient info and treatments, even if one of those never changed. Patients could change their personal information, which will be reflected in medical history, but it doesn't affect treatments.

I am a bit confused on how to model this. Please help!

Comment: Identify behavior of your system. Data will follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that Aggregates, and by extension Bounded Contexts (BC), are a grouping of data and business logic that belong together (and most likely things that need to change transactionally). The data that an aggregate contains is there because the business logic needs it, not because some application screen needs it. This is very important to clear up some confusion and to free you of some constraints in order to design your aggregates.

For example, when you display the Medical History to the user, you might want to show the Patient's name, address, age and so on, and also the treatments prices, but if you think about it, you don't need any of this to manage the Medical History. From what you say, the Medical History has a Record Number, a PatientId, and a list of TreatmentIds with maybe the Dates when they were done.

When you want to display the Medical History to the user, you can use UI Composition. So, you get the Medical History (which is mostly a bunch of Ids and dates). Then from the Medical History's PatientId, you can get the Patients's information from the BC that owns it. From the TreatmentIds, you can get the Treatment descriptions from some BC that owns that and their prices from the BC they belong to.

So, based on that, you can build your aggregates not based on the "relevant names" on your domain like Patient, Treatment or Dentist, but by the business logic they implement.

This is just wild guessing, but I can think of:

BC Marketing (for lack of a better name): Contains the descriptions of all treatments, information about the Dentists, Information about the rooms and materials, etc. So, texts, pictures and other details.

BC Finances: Contains information about the prices of each treatment, payment records of each payment, credits and debits of each patient, etc. In charge of keeping track of all these things. For example, it could know when a treatment starts/ends and depending on the Patient's record, require 50 or 100% payment. There's no need of direct relation to the Medical History here, it only needs to know if it's the first treatment or not.

BC Scheduling: In charge of scheduling new treatments and keep track of when they start and finish. This could contain the History, or it could potentially be somewhere else if necessary.

BC Medical: In charge of keeping all the medical records, allergies, medical details of the status of the teeth, etc.

BC Patients Care: In charge of tracking patients' information, name, nationality, contact details, etc.

Once you have an idea of the Bounded Context you can define the aggregates. There can be one or more per BC. Also, some things might not be an aggregate. For example, the Medical History might not require an actual aggregate if it's basically a record of treatment Ids and the dates they were made and there's no business logic associated (the history is not going to deny a treatment, have opinions on when a treatment should happen and so on, it's just a history).

Don't take this as a recommended design, but just as a thought process to come up with your own solution.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Medical History is just a bag for Id's and dates. It does not have any relevant behaviour. After thinking about the behaviour in reality I realized that the Dentist performs the dental treatment on a patient. The treatment does not have much behaviour, neither does the patient (though he can update some personal info). In this context, if I define the Dentist as an Aggregate root, and when he performs (let's call it) _ApplyTreatment(Treatment, Patient)_, how do I propagate that effect on the Patient entity/aggregate? (like adding to its treatments record)

Comment: Are you suggesting that this application should have 5 Bounded Contexts? Please note that Eric Evans' recommendation for BC is to have a separate DB and Code base for each BC... which means this application would have 5 DBs... also please note that calling out a different bounded context is discouraged in DDD... these 5 BC are heavily dependent on each other. I humbly disagree with with this suggestion.

Comment: @HoomanBahreini I don't suggest specifically 5 BCs, I'm only explaining how you'd apply DDD in a context like this. 5 DBs are a detail. You can use one DB with different schemas if that works for you better. Different code base yes, although you could use monorepo too. Who said anything about calling out different BCs? I would certainly not do that and I don't see the need. Heavily dependent? please explain why. Are you suggesting to stuff everything in a single BC? like treatment prices together with appointment schedules and patients alergies? Isn't that's what DDD discourages?

Comment: @FernanJC I don't think that a Dentist aggregate would have an ApplyTreatment operation. To me, this sounds more like having Use Cases where a Treatment is created, started, completed, etc. Aggregates are transactional boundaries, so think what needs to happen transactionally and what can happen in an eventual consistent manner. You don't want two incompatible medications to be added to a Treatment while, so PrescriptMedication needs to be transactional and avoid concurrency issues, but changing the Dentist profile picture or phone number doesn't have to be transactional with ApplyTreatment

Comment: So, to answer your question: everything that needs to be transactional is stored and changed at once within the aggregate. The other things, are eventually consistent and can be changed using Events. This is like this because the things that need to change transactionally won't grow a lot, but the rest of the things might never stop growing. Eg. a Treatment can be canceled and that's one thing. But the reasons that trigger it can keep growing: the Patient is not paying his bills, the patient died or moved to another country. These things will be implemented somewhere else and publish events

Comment: Really interesting. I am still thinking that, in reality (under this clinic) the dentist performs a dental treatment on a patient, and then writes that down on the medical history. How would you map such behavior on DDD? I believe the whole idea behind DDD is to abstract as much reality as you can into code, so it makes sense from a developer perspective, as well as a domain expert one.

Comment: Yes, but everything was manual, you wouldn't have the Dentists doing a lot of manual work keeping historical records. You'd have the Dentists doing the treatments and a "record keeper" populating the Medical History of each patient. The Dentists don't even need to know that this history exists. Simply, the record keeper would ask the Dentists to inform him every time they started and ended a treatment for a patient (and all other interesting "events"). Potentially, you want other things in the history that don't come from the Dentist (maybe from the patient or from someone or something else)

Comment: So, you don't want many people or "things" concerned about keeping this history. You just want one thing concerned about it, listening to Events that happen in the system. Personally, I don't think the Medical History is an aggregate. It's basically a record that keeps growing and there's not much business logic to enforce, and even less transactionability.

Comment: Thanks! I think I have a lot of homework to do, but this really helped me picturing the domain model better. I do am concern about introducing a Record Keeper notion into the language since it is not something spoken on the domain (they don't have a Record Keeper working, the Dentist does the job of keeping records). Maybe it is part of DDD to also evolve the business blurry language sometimes?

Comment: Yeah, I didn't mean you have to introduce that concept per se, it was just to highlight that it's not a direct responsibility of the Dentist. In software, the Medical History can take care of itself. You simply listen to events and write the history, there's no need to define an "Actor" for this action. So, it's not that the dentist does everything. The dentist just updates the Treatment and the History is automatically updated.

Comment: In any case, don't take my comments as solutions or recommendations. I'm just expressing a thought process. Every domain is different and you'll keep understanding it better and better by talking to stakeholders and users.

Comment: I greatly appreciate your answers, they are really helping me out on understanding the modeling thinking process better. I wish we could continue this conversation and QA, but I am feeling in the need to close the question, so it does not get out of hand. I hope we can keep in contact! Best regards

Comment: No problem. Feel free to reach out.

Answer (score 1):

Entities have an Id where as Value Objects have structure identity which means if two value objects have the same value then they are the same.

In case of Money, there is no difference between two $5 bills, so it can be a value object.

You have not described the role and attributes of Tooth and Signature.

In case of Tooth, does it matter whose Tooth is it? Can You replace a patient's tooth with any other tooth which has the same attributes? If it does matter, then Tooth requires an Id therefore it is an entity.

In case of Signature, how are you going to compare two signatures? Do you have an image recognition software that can compare the look of two Signatures and decide that they are the same? You might have two patients with similar looking signatures, should their signature be treated as the same?

If you choose Medical history to be an Aggregate, then you should treat it as one object. Do you want to load the entire Medical history, in order to add a new Treatment to it? Can a Treatment be associated with another Entity, such as Dentist?  If you can use a portion of Medical history (such as Treatment) individually then it is not an aggregate.

Some good tutorials:

1. *[Entity vs Value Object](https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/posts/entity-vs-value-object-the-ultimate-list-of-differences/) by Vladimir Khorikov*
2. *[Entities, Value Objects, Aggregates and Roots](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2008/05/21/entities-value-objects-aggregates-and-roots/) by Jimmy Bogard*

Comment: A Treatment requires a Dentist to do it, as well as a Patient to apply it to. I think am comfortable with it being an Entity. Treatments don't make sense without a Patient, so maybe the Patient is an Aggregate Root, as well as Dentist. I have doubts with Medical History. I think it could be an Aggreate Root too since it has multiple entities data in it. Can aggregate roots share data? Like, I can have a Patient Aggregate Root, and Medical History Aggregate Root, and just communicate those two.

Comment: An Aggregate is group of Entities/Value Objects that should be modified as one unit. But it does not mean that you should find an Aggregate for every collection of objects... it's true that Medical History contains other Entities, it does not mean that it has to be an Aggregate (it can be an Entity too, an Entity can belong to another Entity)... also note that an Entity such as Treatment cannot belong to multiple Aggregates. It is perfectly valid for Treatment, Patient and Dentist to be entities, with some sort of relationship...

Comment: Interesting. How do you communicate entities that belong to different aggregates? I am coming to the conclusion that the Dentist is an Aggregate, as well as Patient. They change for different reasons, but also a Dentist could make a change to a Treatment under Patient aggregate (when he performs a treatment). Is it fine that one aggregate mutates another one? Or the Patient-Treatment update command does not require a Dentist interaction, but rather just his Id?

Comment: Be careful not to fall for the Aggregate per "name" trap. The fact that you have clear concepts like Dentist, Treatment, and Patient doesn't mean that they match one to one to Aggregates. That's why there are BCs in DDD. From a scheduling point of view a Treatment might have one or more appointments (plus a DentistId and a PatientId). From a medical point of view a treatment might have teeth and medication. From a financial point of view a Treatment will have costs, price, fees, installments, etc.

Comment: Thanks!! I totally missed the DDD perspective there. @FrancescCastells you are right, a Treatment entity varies based on the context it is being discussed.